# Pass down label element as a prop in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code:

```
<div className="input-field">
    <label htmlFor="timeObjective">Time Objective</label>
    <FrequencySet label='label'/> //HERE
</div>
```

I would like to pass down the `label` itself so that in the `FrequencySet` component where I am receiving it as an argument (`label: HTMLLabelElement` in typescript) I can clear the text of that label with `label.innerHTML = '';` in a specific moment.

Can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to pass down the label itself so that in the `FrequencySet` component where I am receiving it as an argument (label: `HTMLLabelElement` in typescript)

You can absolutely pass down `label={<label htmlFor="timeObjective">Time Objective</label>}`.

> I can clear the text of that label with `label.innerHTML = '';` in a specific moment.

If you are manipulating the DOM directly in React then you are almost always doing things wrong.  Your components should render in a predictable and consistent way.  If you clear the text with `label.innerHTML` you might find that the label text re-appears when the component re-renders.

---

The state of the label text needs to be something that is controlled by React state.  The `string` text itself could be a state.

```
const [labelText, setLabelText] = useState('Time Objective');

const clearLabel = () => setLabelText('');
```

```
<label htmlFor="timeObjective">{labelText}</label>
```

If all you are doing is clearing, then you could control it with a `boolean` state like `showLabel`.

```
const [showLabel, setShowLabel] = useState(true);

const clearLabel = () => setShowLabel(false);
```

```
<label htmlFor="timeObjective">{showLabel ? 'Time Objective' : ''}</label>
```

You can pass down `clearLabel`, `setLabelText` or whatever methods you need as props to `FrequencySet`.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the text of your label as the state value of your component and pass the `setState` function down to the `FrequencySet` as a prop. Inside `FrequencySet` call `setState`:

```
const [labelText, setLabelText] = useState<string>("Time Objective");
const clearLabelText = useCallback(() => setLabelText("")); // against unnecessary renders

<FrequencySet clearLabelText={clearLabelText} />
```